# Facebook Like Box - photos does not appearing

Tags: facebook, photo

this is my like box: http://probto.sk/content/7-aktuality

and this is the FB page: https://www.facebook.com/probto

as you can see, photos from FB page doesnt show on like box on probto.sk
what is wrong?
can you help me please?

PS: sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

In your script for the lightbox, change show_faces=false to show_faces=true.
And for the other images, make sure the source is correct.
Facebook uses background images in the stylesheets where the url goes to a third server and the image names since to be hashes.   Check the image source in your script and make sure it does not change in your site.  So far, I did not see any image location in your script for your photos.

Answer (score 0):

the new embedded-post-plugin could be the reason why they dropped the image support... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

Answer (score 0):

This is "by design".  The limited space of social plugins like the Like Box and Activity Feed means FB has to display 'compact' versions of large stories like photos.  If you look at the CSS, you'll see the DIVs are tagged '!important' (not important).